# Unbalancing error while create vendor bills in Odoo13

Tags: odoo, invoice, odoo-13

Recently I have been trying to create vendor bills in odoo13 by code by apparently every time I run the code I get a message "Cannot create unbalanced journal entry. Ids: [177] Differences debit - credit: [3.5]"

3.5 in my unit_price.

**My code is below:**

```
payment_move = self.env['account.move'].create({
    'type': 'in_invoice',
    'partner_id': self.client.id,
})
payment_move.invoice_line_ids.create({'move_id': payment_move.id,
                                      'quantity': 1.0,
                                      'price_unit': 3.5,
                                      'account_id': self.env['account.account'].search(
        [('user_type_id', '=', self.env.ref('account.data_account_type_expenses').id)], limit=1).id})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In latest Odoo v13 'account.invoice' replaced by 'account.move'

Comment: Why you did not specify the products in your vendor bill?

Comment: product not required also it is not a mandatory field.

Comment: Try to pass `invoice_line_ids` in `create` method. `'invoice_line_ids': [(0,  0, {'move_id': ...})]`